# inverse of quadratic log functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

Can a Log function with a quadratic have an inverse function? The specific question is to find the inverse of 
$$f(x) = \log_2(x^2-3x-4)$$ 
The function already fails the horizontal line test, but apparently there is a function of

If $$x>4, \quad f^{-1}(x) = \frac{3+ \sqrt{2^{x+2}+25}}{2}$$

If $$x<-1, \quad f^{-1}(x) = \frac{3- \sqrt{2^{x+2}+25}}{2} $$ 
I was able to find this by swapping the x and y around, but why does it have an inverse function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you did that by dividing the function to two parts which individually are invertible.
[image: graph]

Comment: So to clarify, when it is specified $x>4$, is that simply referring to the original log function, or is that the domain of the inverse (exponential) function, having the inverse something like a piecemeal function?

Comment: $x>4$ (or $x<-1$) refer's to the original function because you divided the original function and after that you found the inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle f(x)=\log_2(x^2-3x-4)=y, x^2-3x-4=2^y $

$\displaystyle\implies f^{-1}(y)=x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{25+2^{y+2}}}2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_2(x^2-3x-4)=y$$
$$2^y=x^2-3x-4$$
$$x^2-3x-4-2^y=0$$
$$x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{25+2^{y+2}}}{2}$$